# MySQL - select 3 tables with correct left join syntax

Tags: mysql, syntax, left-join

Hope you can help me with correct syntax of a SQL query (using MySQL 5.5.25).

I have 3 tables:

- data
- data_tmp
- users

`data` table is empty - has it's own structure but no rows

**data**:

```
id | name | who
----------------
```

**data_tmp**:

```
id | cars | who
---------------
1  | lambo| 2
```

**users**

```
who | name |
------------
 2  | john
```

My query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    users.name, 
    (SELECT count(id) FROM data WHERE who = 1) as number, 
    data_tmp.cars 
FROM 
    users, data, data_tmp 
WHERE 
    users.who = 2 
    AND data_tmp.who = 2 
    AND data.who = 2
```

This of course returns an empty result (there is no row that suits to all parameters because `data` is empty).

What I would like to achieve is:

```
users.name | number | data_tmp.cars |
-------------------------------------
 john      |    0   | lambo         |
```

I am sure I have to - in some way - use `LEFT JOIN` but can't find correct syntax. Hope you can help me.

Kalreg

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... details of features are often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this a try (*without using subquery*)

```
SELECT  a.name, b.cars, count(c.id) as  number
FROM    users a 
            INNER JOIN data_tmp b
                on a.who = b.who
            LEFT JOIN data c
                on a.who = c.who AND
                   a.name = c.name
WHERE    a.who = 2 
GROUP BY a.name, b.cars
```

this works on different servers:

**[MSSQL SERVER @ SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e16a/1)** 
**[MYSQL @ SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e16a/1)**

Comment: this cant work properly i.e because there is no 'name' column in c table.

Comment: did you test it? that's why i'm using `LEFT JOIN`. `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` are two different things. click the sql fiddle links below :)

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is right: you have to use left JOIN, in this way :

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.name, (SELECT count(id) FROM data WHERE who = 1) as number, data_tmp.cars 
FROM users
JOIN data_tmp USING (who)
LEFT JOIN data USING(who)
WHERE users.who = 2
```

Comment: thanks for answer! unfortunatelly this returns incorect syntax :( can you check it on your db?

Comment: What database are you using ?

Comment: better but does return empty result

Comment: No, it works, see here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e16a/7/0 However i have updated my answer ..

Comment: john idea works fine for me (see below). I have some troubles with 'using' formula, i dont know why. anyways thanks for help!