# MySQL conditional join - is this syntax legal?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query with multiple joins:

```
SELECT * FROM posts k
...
LEFT JOIN groups gr on k.group_id=gr.id
LEFT JOIN events ev on k.event_id=ev.id
...
etc.
```

I want to decrease the number of joins because not in every query all of them are needed.
So, there is no need to join table **groups** if **k.group.id='0'**,
there is no need to join table **events** if **k.event.id='0'**

Is there any way how to create a query with join conditions?

The following joins work OK but I am not sure that this syntax is legal:

```
LEFT JOIN groups gr on k.group_id > 0 and k.group_id=gr.id
LEFT JOIN events ev on k.event_id > 0 and k.event_id=ev.id
```

Is it possible to do this in another way?

Comment: you can use any expression in join, e.g. "on rand() > rand()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the syntax

```
LEFT JOIN groups gr on k.group_id > 0 and k.group_id=gr.id
LEFT JOIN events ev on k.event_id > 0 and k.event_id=ev.id
```

is perfectly legal. If you want to add condition to your JOINS then this is the way to proceed. Also you can make it more readable by writing like:

```
LEFT JOIN groups gr on k.group_id=gr.id and k.group_id > 0 
LEFT JOIN events ev on k.event_id=ev.id and k.event_id > 0
```

(*Note its not mandatory, its just the matter of readability as I find it more readable to first see the JOINing columns and then the condition*)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the following SQL syntax looks fine to me.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON condition1 AND condition2
LEFT JOIN table3 ON condition3 AND condition4;
```

Additionally, you may want to take a look at the following links for more information on this.

[MySQL LEFT JOIN 3 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222097/mysql-left-join-3-tables)

[MySQL - select 3 tables with correct left join syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708464/mysql-select-3-tables-with-correct-left-join-syntax)

[Left Joins to link three or more tables](http://www.wellho.net/solutions/mysql-left-joins-to-link-three-or-more-tables.html)